# Why was Eric Stoltz substituted by Michael J Fox?

Tags: back-to-the-future, actors, production

I read in many places that Eric Stoltz was substituted by Michael J Fox in the film Back to the future. And the main reason is that Eric wasn't bringing the screwball energy the film needed. Is this the only reason? Something else happened?

Comment: http://www.vulture.com/2015/06/how-back-to-the-future-replaced-eric-stoltz.html

Comment: http://www.vulture.com/2015/10/christopher-lloyd-on-back-to-the-future-day.html

Answer (score 3):

Summary of the videos - he was a good actor but they wanted something more comedic. After several weeks of filming, in consultation with producers and others, Zemekis finally decided he wasn't getting the performance he desired for this particular role and film. Lloyd himself had no idea the change was going to / needed to happen

Director Zemekis and Producer Speilberg on the topic:

Christopher Lloyd on the topic:

Comment: Answers which rely heavily on linked works are generally viewed as quite low quality. If the links die, your answer becomes pretty meaningless.

Comment: Glad I put the summary there!

Comment: It's a bit terse.

Comment: Is that **one** line you wrote about Christopher Lloyd the only highlight of the video? He had no personal opinion on the matter? Also, reading *"Lloyd himself"* confused me, as I thought you were referring to the guy getting replaced, which didn't match the name in the question title.